# Workaround for using the internal class AboutHandler in RCP for which access is discouraged

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, internal-class

I'm aware of why using internal classes is discouraged, and am generally happy to stick to not using them.

However, in my RCP I want to use a `command` rather than an `action` to display the `About dialog`. Hence I have extended `org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.AboutHandler` for my handler class, which is discouraged.

Is there a workaround available to use this class or rather its functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you could reuse the existing contribution:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on Mac)
2. Select the About from your Eclipse instance
3. Will open the Plug-in menu spy that should provide you with the ID of the menu contribution (basically command ID) of the About command.

If you have the command ID, you could simply specify a menu contribution for the item, as shown in the following [tutorial](http://blog.eclipse-tips.com/2009/05/commands-part-7-adding-standard.html) using the cut/copy/paste items.

Comment: Thanks. Apart from that the hotkey for the Plug-in menu spy is `ALT+SHIFT+F2` (which was easy to find out when your suggestion didn't work :)), this is very helpful. The menu spy said that the `About` menu and popup is indeed implemented via the `ActionFactory.ABOUT` `action` rather than a `command`, so I guess I'll just stick with the `action` myself.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about the hotkey - I am using a Mac which has some keybindings different. I updated my answer to represent this.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add that you get the default AboutHandler for free when you depend on `org.eclipse.ui` (which provides the RCP workbench support), and prior to that being the default simply creating the `org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory.ABOUT` action and registering it in your `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` would fill in a handler for the command for free.

Comment: Thanks. That's how I've done it before I read (in Jeff McAffer's book) that `commands` are to be preferred over `actions`. So I've tried the `ui.internal.AboutHandler` as a handler (discouraged), and simply extending that class (also discouraged). If I cannot find a decent way (haven't tried out Zoltán's suggestion yet), I'll simply go back to using the `action`.

Comment: And why don't you get the handler for free?  is it not defined as the defaultHandler in your target platform `org.eclipse.ui/plugin.xml`?

Comment: Hi @Paul, the `defaultHandler` that is in `org.eclipse.ui/plugin.xml` is the inner class `org.eclipse.ui.internal.about.AboutHandler`... 

But perhaps I simply didn't get your point correctly? I don't have a `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java` in my plugin (only the `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor`)...

Comment: My point is if that is already defined as a default handler in `org.eclipse.ui` you should simply be able to add the about command to the menu.